# Blank Page After Submitting Form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add a record to my DB using Laravel but after submitting a form I get a blank screen and no logs. Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach(Auth::user()->test as $data) {
                if($request->name == $data->name) {
                    return back()->with('wrong', trans('settings.isset.name')); 
                }
                else {
                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'name' => 'required',
                    ]);

                    $name = Name::store($request);

                    return back()->with('message', trans('settings.add.name')); 
                }
            }
    }
```

And there is, of course, a normal working form. Before when I didn't have `foreach` it was working, but not it isn't.

Comment: A blank page means errors. Turn on your error checking.

Comment: Check your server logs, and the Laravel logs found in `/storage/logs`

Comment: Put  `return` outside of foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this can be caused when `Auth::user()->test` is empty.
Therefore code inside the `foreach` loop is not executed and nothing is returned.

You could try putting the `return` statement to the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do the job

```html
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $error = false;
    $errors = [];

        foreach(Auth::user()->test as $data) {
                if($request->name == $data->name) {
                    $error = true;
                    $errors['wrong'] = trans('settings.isset.name'); 
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'name' => 'required',
                    ]);

                    $name = Name::store($request);

                }
            }

        if($error)
            return back()->with($errors);

        return back()->with('message', trans('settings.add.name')); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below .htaccess
`Options +ExecCGI
    addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
    Options -MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to method="POST".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).